# Select2 Multi-Value Select Boxes not displaying correctly

Tags: jquery-chosen, multiple-select, jquery-select2

**EDIT:** 
I have figured out what my problem was for this perticular issue.

**SOLUTION:** For this perticular issue I had permission issues. Since I copied the chosen and select2 project folders straight into my application apparently the permissions were incorrect. The solution is either creating the plugin files within your project while developing, or doing a    **'chmod 0755 -R select2/'**    in terminal given you're using a *nix machine. That was it. It wasn't any conflict issues between chosen and select2 or anything like that.

**Original post:**

I'm trying to create a clean Multi-Value Select Box using Select2.
I've tried both Select2 and Chosen.js and the results are the same.
The box doesn't display correctly. It displays an old style ugly multi select box like if there wasn't any javascript involved.

Here is an image showing how it displays: http://d.pr/i/bUa5

What I'm trying to get is a multi select box like the one in this forum.

Hope someone can help?

Here is my test code:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<title>Select2 Example</title>
<link href="select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="chosen/chosen.css">
</head>
<body>
<form>

    <select id="e1" multible>
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="AR">Arizona</option>
        <option value="CA">California</option>
        <option value="WS">Wisconsin</option>
        <option value="NY">New York</option>
        <option value="TX">Texas</option>
        <option value="OR">Orlando</option>
    </select>

        <select id="chzn-select" data-placeholder="Choose a country..." style="width:350px;" multiple class="chzn-select" tabindex="4">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="AR">Arizona</option>
        <option value="CA">California</option>
        <option value="WS">Wisconsin</option>
        <option value="NY">New York</option>
        <option value="TX">Texas</option>
        <option value="OR">Orlando</option>
    </select>
</form> 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="select2.js"></script>
<script src="chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>

<script>

    $(".chzn-select").chosen();

    $(document).ready(function() { $("#e1").select2(function() {
        placeholder: "Select State"
    }); });
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had loads of trouble with this, but managed to get it working.
Differences between my code and yours:

My document ready function is in my head, not my body, also i had just $("#e1").select2(); No inner function.

Have you tried when running in a browser, right clicking and choosing view source and opening up your .js and .css files to make sure they are visible to your html?

Lastly for the select2 you have put multible instead of multiple

I binned chosen as i couldnt get it to work, but select 2 is built on it, so i'd go for that. Also as they are built on one another this could be causing some conflict, so i'd get rid of chosen and try that.

Hope this helps

ps: I have implemented it this way, but now when i remove options from the multiple select, they are gone from my drop down choice and cannot be re-added. The examples for this are not very straight forward, wish there were some simple examples for this useful add on!

Comment: thank you for your feedback. I've figured out what my problem was and I'll be editing my post to show the solution :)

Comment: Thats cool, now you have it working, are you experiencing what I said? That if you select an option and then remove it, you cannot re-select it? Be good to know if this issue is just happening on my implementation or not